# Which is the best / most reliable car automatic gearbox technology for frequent climb mountain

Tags: automatic-transmission

Today we have in the market so many car with different types of automatic gearbox system, produced by many manufactures, like ZF, Getrag, Aisin... producing from conventional automatic gearbox, to CVT, and many other solutions in between.

I was wondering before buying a new car, that it will travel and climb many mountain, with frequent variable inclination, what type of technical solution it would be the most reliable and long lasting? it might be an hard job for a CVT? or it would be better a Twin-clutch or conventional automatic gearbox?

Thanks.
Regards.
Enrico

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is subjective and primarily opinion based